# how to add hindi language support to struts webapplication

Tags: java, struts

I am creating  Web application using the struts 1.2. On which I have to add the Hindi language support to my Web application.I have created the Application_hi.properties file in which I have key equal to Hindi word. But it is giving the error like "some character cannot be map using ISO-8859-1 character encoding".

thanks in advance................

Answer (score 1):

Hindi is does not come under ISO-8859-1 Character encoding, 
The contents in the properties files are encoded in the 8-bit characters of ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin-1) which contains most “regular” characters but lacks support for language specific characters like ü Ü é or ñ.

So i was using the other utilities to convert from one encoding to the other encoding
I think you can check this link for more information and may be handy for you 
1) http://okapi.sourceforge.net/Release/Rainbow/Help/index.html
2)http://okapi.sourceforge.net/Release/Utilities/Help/encodingconversion.htm

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: how to use UTF-8 character encoding in struts application.

Comment: struts-config:
<controller contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
/>
Jsp page directive:
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"
%>